# PHP Button click call different Pages

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a landing page and there should be one download button. So when the button was clicked and the form has been completed correctly the user will be redirected to the thank you page but when the form has not been completed correctly I will redirect the user to an error page. How can I realize this?

[image: My form]

My code for the form:

```
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="email" name="iptEmail" placeholder="MaxMustermann@gmail.com" required />
    <br /><br />
    <img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false"><img src="img/reloadCaptcha.png" alt="reloadCaptcha.png"></a>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="captcha_code" id="iptCaptcha" placeholder="Code" size="10" minlength="6" maxlength="6" required />
    <br /><br />
    <button name="btnSubmit">DOWNLOAD</button> 
    <?php
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';
    $securimage = new Securimage();
    if(array_key_exists('btnSubmit',$_POST)){
        if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
            $_SESSION['status'] = "error";
        } else {
            if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
                $mailKunde = $_POST['iptEmail'];
                $betreff = "";
                $message = "";
                $absName = "";
                $absMail = "";
                $replyTo = "";
                $anhang = "./data/test.zip";
                mail_att($mailKunde, $betreff, $message, $absName, $absMail, $replyTo, $anhang);
                $_SESSION['status'] = "thanks";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

My code for the body:

```
    <body>
    <?php
    if ($_SESSION['status'] == "home") {
        include('php/home.php');
    } elseif ($_SESSION['status'] == "error") {
        include('php/error.php');
    } elseif ($_SESSION['status'] == "thanks") {
        include('php/thanks.php');
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: By validating the data, and then doing a redirect based on a conditional. Please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: ok I have updatet my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following,
you may redirect the user to a different page using this line of code:

```
<?php
if(some_condition...){
    header("Location: someotherplace.php");
}
```

also, if you have already sent html output before this line, you can simply emit a javascript redirect:

```
<?php
if(some_condition...){
    echo("<script>;location.href='someotherplace.php';</script>");
}
```